# Delete all duplicated entries where multiple columns duplicates match

Tags: mysql

I need to add this contrain to my table called 'kraken'

```
ALTER TABLE kraken ADD UNIQUE unique_index(exchange_pair,timestamp);
```

this shows me that i have duplicated entries on those 2 columns (exchange_pair and timestamp)
so first i have to delete all the duplicated entries based on those 2 columns

this is what i found but im not sure if my query would work since i need to delete only duplicated entris with column 'exchange_pair' and 'timestamp', i dont want to mess things up with my table
https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-delete-duplicate-rows/

Comment: My advise is that you create a replica of table and do the test in there, with query like "CREATE TABLE temp_table AS SELECT * FROM original_table" and perform operations over temp_table, also you can use the temp_table as backup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to remove duplicates is to join the table with itself:

```
DELETE z.* 
  FROM kraken AS w
  JOIN kraken AS z ON z.exchange_pair = w.exchange_pair
                  AND z.timestamp = w.timestamp
                  AND z.id > w.id -- or what primary key you have
;
```

All duplicates will be deleted except one with the lowest `id`.